# MessageEmbed field values may not be empty error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Everytime I execute an embed command, I get this error:

```
/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:425
if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
 RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
```

This happened after I added this command to the code, and then broke all the embed commands:

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${PREFIX}uptime`)){
    let totalSeconds = (client.uptime / 1000)
    let days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 86400)
    let hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600)
    totalSeconds %= 3600;
    let minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60)
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
    message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setColor('RANDOM').setTitle('Uptime Info').setDescription(`**Days: ${days}
    Hours: ${hours}
    Minutes: ${minutes}
    Seconds: ${seconds}**`))
    }
})
```

I tried to delete the files from github repository and then I made a new repository with the files uninstalled and installed again discord.js in the bot files but it still didn't work.

Comment: It seems to be a validation problem coming from that object. Are all those values valid when you call it?

Comment: Would it be possible to add the versions being used and some context on how you added the code, and what do you mean by 'Everytime I execute and embed command'?

Comment: ‘Everytime I execute an* embed command’ sorry for my bad English, I’m trying to say that the commands that are like that, MessageEmbed() are all broken for some reason, don’t work anymore and give me the same error and yeah, all the values are valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

const moment = require("moment");
        require("moment-duration-format");
        const duration = moment.duration(client.uptime).format(" D [days], H [hours], m [mins], s [seconds]");